# How do I determine the cost Basis for IRA funds converted to Roth?

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-conversion

I converted $100,000  from rollover ira to Roth IRA in 2021.
What is the basis for this converted amount? I entered zero. I want to make sure I am doing it right.

Comment: Are you trying to determine taxes on the conversion or on withdrawing the money from your Roth IRA? What form are you filling out that asks for your basis?

Comment: For your first question answer is ‘No.’ I am using TaxAct to do my taxes. On that system they ask for basis to fill out form 8606.

Comment: Note 'basis' in a trad IRA or employer plan is NOT 'cost basis', which is a quite different concept that applies (only) to 'regular' aka 'taxable' investments and accounts (NOT tax-deferred ones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The money in the IRA because it is a rollover IRA is made up of three things:

- The pre-tax money you put into a 401(k).
- The money the company put in which is always pre-tax.
- The growth of those contributions.

There can also be a forth source of the funds: post-tax contributions you made to the 401(k). Before the government allowed the Roth 401(k) you were allowed to put money into the account that was post-tax. You could withdraw those contributions without taxes and penalties, but the growth would face taxes and penalties if your weren't 59.5/ It wasn't as good as a Roth.

in the instructions for [IRS form 8606](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8606):

> Basis.
>
> Your basis in traditional, SEP, and SIMPLE IRAs is the total of all
> your nondeductible contributions and nontaxable amounts included in
> rollovers made to these IRAs minus the total of all your nontaxable
> distributions, adjusted if necessary (see the instructions for line 2,
> later).

So that would mean if the IRA has non-deductable contributions, or post-tax contributions that were rolled into it, the basis might not be zero.

looking at line 2:

> Line 2
>
> Generally, if this is the first year you are required to file Form
> 8606, enter -0-. Otherwise, use the Total Basis Chart to find the
> amount to enter on line 2.
>
> However, you may need to enter an amount that is more than -0- (even
> if this is the first year you are required to file Form 8606) or
> increase or decrease the amount from the chart if your basis changed
> because of any of the following.
>
> - You had a return of excess traditional IRA contributions (see Return of Excess Traditional IRA Contributions, earlier).
> - Incident to divorce, you transferred or received part or all of a traditional, SEP, or SIMPLE IRA (see the last bulleted item under Line
>   7, later).
> - You rolled over any nontaxable portion of your qualified retirement plan to a traditional, SEP, or SIMPLE IRA that wasn’t previously
>   reported on Form 8606, line 2. Include the nontaxable portion on line 2

That last bullet matches the first quoted section. A qualified retirement plan would be a 401(k) or one of its cousins: 403(b), TSP...

So unless you made post-tax or nondeductible contributions, the basis the first year you are using this form is almost always zero.

Note: the total basis chart just tells you where to find the data from a earlier tax year, because line numbers have changed.

Comment: I had employer sponsored plan with TIAA. After retirement I am doing rollover to Vanguard in 10 installments. Last year I converted the amount from rollover to Roth. From what I understand the basis is zero. Thanks.